# memory allocation of 59365708876800 bytes failed in Deno, Mongo databse

Tags: mongodb, deno, oak

I'm creating API using `Deno` and my database as Mongo Database. I try to run my File like below and I got an error like `memory allocation of 59365708876800 bytes failed` What went wrong here?

```
D:\Deno Documentation\deno6>deno run --allow-net --allow-write --allow-read --allow-plugin --unstable 
./index.js
INFO load deno plugin "deno_mongo" from local "D:\Deno Documentation\deno6\.deno_plugins\deno_mongo_eba1b6cad1c0aae92825a91f5e45edba.dll"
memory allocation of 59365708876800 bytes failed
D:\Deno Documentation\deno6>
```

> router.js

```
import {Router} from 'https://deno.land/x/oak@v4.0.0/mod.ts';

import Read from './crud/read.js';

const router=new Router();


router.get('/',({response})=>
{
    response.body='API is working';
});

router
    .get('/create',Read);



export default router;
```

> config.js

```
export const PORT=3000;
```

> read.js

```
import {Router} from 'https://deno.land/x/oak@v4.0.0/mod.ts';
import db from '../mongodb.js';

export default async({response})=>{

    const QuestionCollection=db.collection('Question');

    try {
        const question=await QuestionCollection.find();

        response.body=question;

    } catch (error) {

    }
}
```

> mongodb.js

```
import { MongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.8.0/mod.ts";


const client = new MongoClient();
client.connectWithUri("mongodb+srv://///");

const db = client.database("Question");

export default db;
```

> index.js

```
import {Application} from 'https://deno.land/x/oak@v4.0.0/mod.ts';

import {PORT} from './config.js';
import router from './router.js';



const app=new Application();

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

console.log(`http://localhost:${PORT}`);

await app.listen({port:PORT});
```

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: I shared. Thank you

Comment: What's your Deno version¿?

Comment: `deno 1.0.0
v8 8.4.300
typescript 3.9.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `deno 1.0.0` you should use `mongo@v0.6.0` or `mongo@v0.7.0` instead of `0.8.0`

See `deno_mongo` [releases](https://github.com/manyuanrong/deno_mongo/releases)

Comment: I got an error, if i using `mongo@v0.6.0`, `error: Uncaught Error: The plugin must be initialized before use
    throw new Error("The plugin must be initialized before use");
          ^
    at dispatch (https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.6.0/ts/util.ts:64:11)
    at MongoClient.connectWithUri (https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.6.0/ts/client.ts:97:18)
    at file:///D:/Deno%20Documentation/deno6/mongodb.js:5:8`  if i using for me, `mongo@v0.7.0` is working,

Comment: `mongo@v0.7.0` is working fine. but according to the documentation, `mongo@v0.6.0` gives an error

Comment: Then 0.7.0 is  the one.